# NestJS testing error: Cannot find compiled js file in E2E test mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, nestjs

I am having an issue with running an E2E test. This is the default E2E test file structure that's generated by nestcli.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('test');
  });
});
```

I am running the tests using `mocha`, my package.json test script command is:

```
"test": "mocha --exit --require ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts test/*.spec.ts"
```

The error that I see is:

```
 1) AppController (e2e)
       "before each" hook for "/ (GET)":
     Error: File <root_path>/src/queuemanager/status.processor.js does not exist
      at Queue.setHandler (node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:641:13)
      at Queue.process (node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:610:8)
      at option.processors.forEach (node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.providers.js:27:27)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at buildQueue (node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.providers.js:12:27)
      at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (node_modules/@nestjs/bull/dist/bull.providers.js:57:20)
      at Injector.instantiateClass (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:289:55)
      at callback (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:42:41)
```

The directory structure of my project in `src` is:

```
 $ tree -L 2
.
├── app.controller.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── app.service.ts
├── main.ts
└── queuemanager
    ├── queuemanager.controller.ts
    ├── queuemanager.module.ts
    └── status.processor.ts
```

This is very similar to the example provided in https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/26-queues. Basically, I am creating a queue which uses `status.processor.ts` to process tasks in a separate process. This is what my queuemanager module looks like:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { QueuemanagerController } from './queuemanager.controller';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
          name: 'status',
          processors: [{
            name: 'statusProcessing',
            path: join(__dirname, 'status.processor.js')
          }]
        }),
  ],
  controllers: [QueuemanagerController],
})
export class QueuemanagerModule {}
```

In order to get things to work correctly, I need to provide the compiled path to the `js` file. However, I assume the test is not able to correctly find this for some reason - maybe its not compiled correctly. Hoping to get some help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right answer, but here's what I did to make it work:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { QueuemanagerController } from './queuemanager.controller';
import { join } from 'path';

const filename: string = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? 'status.processor.ts' : 'status.processor.js';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue({
          name: 'status',
          processors: [{
            name: 'statusProcessing',
            path: join(__dirname, filename)
          }]
        }),
  ],
  controllers: [QueuemanagerController],
})
export class QueuemanagerModule {}
```

and set `NODE_ENV=test` in the npm script that runs the test. If someone knows a better way feel free to update.